# How to retrieve google Markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

How to retrieve all existing markers on the public map created by me in javascript.

In html I am adding following tag.

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?mid=zJ463bGh1PYM.kWHWVlcByQeU" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

Now I want to extract all the markers present on this map in Javascript.

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 2):

1. click on the

[image: share image]

2. choose "Download KML"
3. check the "Keep data up to date with network link KML (only usable online)."
4. rename the resulting .kmz file as .zip
5. open the contained .kml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'>
    <Document>
        <name>Untitled layer</name>
        <NetworkLink>
            <name>my-map</name>
            <Link>
                <href>http://mapsengine.google.com/map/kml?mid=zJ463bGh1PYM.kWHWVlcByQeU&amp;lid=zJ463bGh1PYM.ko7uxR2p2yu4</href>
            </Link>
        </NetworkLink>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

6. that contains the external link to the KML that describes your map (`http://mapsengine.google.com/map/kml?mid=zJ463bGh1PYM.kWHWVlcByQeU&amp;lid=zJ463bGh1PYM.ko7uxR2p2yu4`).  Load that on a Google Maps Javascript API v3 map using KmlLayer.

working code snippet:

```js
function initialize() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url: "http://mapsengine.google.com/map/kml?mid=zJ463bGh1PYM.kWHWVlcByQeU&amp;lid=zJ463bGh1PYM.ko7uxR2p2yu4",
        map: map
    });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map_canvas {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style=border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```