# I need to extract lat long data from a google maps url that uses msa and msid

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

When wrapping some web pages i got an iframe like this:

```
<iframe width="870" height="480" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msa=0&amp;hl=pt-BR&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;vpsrc=0&amp;msid=206481929558161217795.0004aa2b76eb8211ac517&amp;z=17&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

the important part of code is the url:

http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msa=0&hl=pt-BR&ie=UTF8&vpsrc=0&msid=206481929558161217795.0004aa2b76eb8211ac517&z=17&output=embed

the question is:

how can i get latitude and longitude data from this google maps url?

Answer (score 0):

The latitude and longitude are not available as part of that URL.  If you download the KML from that map, decompress the resulting KMZ file and look at the KML contained in it, you will see (the coordinates of the displayed marker):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'>
    <Document>
        <name>Untitled layer</name>
        <Placemark>
            <styleUrl>#icon-22</styleUrl>
            <name>Residencial Buena Vista</name>
            <ExtendedData>
            </ExtendedData>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>-49.281449,-16.689937,0.0</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
        <Style id='icon-22'>
            <IconStyle>
                <scale>1.1</scale>
                <Icon>
                    <href>http://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/22-blue-dot.png</href>
                </Icon>
                <hotSpot x='16' y='31' xunits='pixels' yunits='insetPixels'>
                </hotSpot>
            </IconStyle>
        </Style>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var myOptions = {
    center: {
      lat: 0,
      lng: 0
    },
    zoom: 2,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  var geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
    map: map,
    singleInfoWindow: false
  });
  geoXml.parseKmlString(kmlData);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

var kmlData = '<kml><Style id="icon-22"><IconStyle><scale>1.1</scale><Icon><href>http://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/22-blue-dot.png</href></Icon><hotSpot x="16" y="31" xunits="pixels" yunits="insetPixels"></hotSpot></IconStyle></Style><Placemark><styleUrl>#icon-22</styleUrl><name>Residencial Buena Vista</name><Point><coordinates>-49.281449,-16.689937,0.0</coordinates></Point></Placemark></kml>';
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://geoxml3.googlecode.com/svn/branches/polys/geoxml3.js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

Comment: how can i download the KML from that map inside my code (a code that do a get request to a page having that map)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28642206/how-to-retrieve-google-markers/28645728#28645728